# When will IE6 no longer be supported?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

As we all know supporting IE6 with its many well documented quirks is painful but a necessary part of development and supporting with web based technologies. My question is “does anyone know when IE6 is scheduled for end of official Microsoft support (or retirement) or if Microsoft will force an update to IE7 or IE8”?

Comment: Not until an operating system other than Windows XP becomes the de facto OS for businesses.

Comment: How does the cease of official support from Microsoft affect your need to test against or build for IE6? You'll have to do it until the last paying customer stops to use it. Besides - there is no IE7 for Windows 2000, and still people use Windows 2000. Upgrades to XP will not be forced, I guess.

Comment: @Tomalak I work for a government organisation but couldn't find any official information on when it will no longer be supported.

Comment: Probably not until 2022, when HTML5 is ready. (As this article states: http://www.webmonkey.com/blog/HTML_5_Won_t_Be_Ready_Until_2022DOT_Yes__2022DOT)

Comment: The official answer is "IE6 support will end at the same time as Windows XP support." The end of life date for Windows XP was originally going to be in 2010, but was extended significantly, largely due to the failure of Windows Vista. The EoL date is currently set in mid 2013. I can't imagine there will be any further extensions from that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See Microsoft's chart:

http://support.microsoft.com/gp/lifesupsps/#Internet_Explorer

Comment: Cool, so sometime around 13-Jul-2010 for computers running Windows XP Service Pack 2 or 3

Comment: I also found this link (http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2009/05/07/announcing-sharepoint-server-2010-preliminary-system-requirements.aspx) within another Stack Overlfow answer.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I don't support IE6 anymore on websites that I built. Not completely anyway. If you build a website in a sensible way (i.e. use a CSS reset stylesheet, don't futz with margings and paddings on floated containers) then things mostly work on IE6. The content is presentable and usable and otherwise degrades in a reasonable way. I'm done with spending hours on minor style fixes, using AlphaImageLoader hacks on PNG's and other dirty tricks.

The only trick I will employ for IE6 when things really break down is to include an override to simply remove most styles.

In short, I treat IE6 like any other legacy browser. You can access the contents and it's usable. Doing anything more isn't feasible anymore. It takes an extraordinary amount of work for only a little bit of market share (15% and plummeting).

Answer (score 2):

When YOU stop developing for IE6. I suggest you start TODAY!

Comment: Sorry but I work for a government department, and me nor any of my team have any authority on which browser is part of the standard operating system, so I can't stop developing for IE6.